# How can I get python to loop through multiple suffixes and remove them if present?

Tags: python, loops, suffix

I need to remove "ed", "ly", and/or "ing" from any given phrase... originally i defined suff with all 3 as a tuple but it was only removing the first suffix listed. So i've tried another method as shown below but I know I'm not correct. New to python so any help would be appreciated.

````
#initalize test list
test_list = ['Running the boy gladly jumped']
 
# printing original list
print("The original list : " + str(test_list))
 
# initialize suffixes
suff = 'ed'
suff1 = 'ly'
suff2 = 'ing'
 
# Suffix removal from String list
# using loop + remove() + endswith()
for word in test_list[:]:
    if word.endswith(suff):
        test_list.word[:-len(suff)]
    elif word.endswith(suff1):
        test_list.word[:-len(suff1)]
    elif word.endswith(suff2):
        test_list.text[:-len(suff2)]
 
# printing result
print("List after removal of suffix elements : "+ str(test_list))```
````

Answer (score 2):

This expression:

```
    if word.endswith(suff):
        test_list.word[:-len(suff)]
```

doesn't do anything -- `test_list.word` isn't valid because `word` isn't an attribute of `test_list`, and simply slicing a string doesn't modify it (strings are immutable).

A version of this loop that would do what you intend might be:

```
for i, word in enumerate(test_list):
    if word.endswith(suff):
        test_list[i] = word[:-len(suff)]
    elif word.endswith(suff1):
        test_list[i] = word[:-len(suff1)]
    elif word.endswith(suff2):
        test_list[i] = word[:-len(suff2)]
```

`enumerate` gives us the index `i` of each `word` in `test_list`, and we can use that index to assign a new string to that position in the list.  (Be careful when modifying a list in a loop -- in this case it's okay because we aren't changing the length of the list.)

A simpler solution (one that makes it easy to add new suffixes, and to apply this operation in different situations) might be to put your suffixes in a list:

```
suffixes = ['ed', 'ly', 'ing']
```

define a function that removes the first encountered suffix from a list of suffixes from a word:

```
def remove_suffix(word, suffixes):
    for suff in suffixes:
        if word.endswith(suff):
            return word[:-len(suff)]
    return word
```

and then use that function to redefine your list:

```
test_list = [remove_suffix(word, suffixes) for word in test_list]
```

Comment: Thank you! If I wanted to limit the characters in each word to 8, how would I do that? Sorry this was in a technical and I didn't solve it correctly, so i'm eager to learn. I appreciate your explanation!

Comment: `assert all(len(word) <= 8 for word in test_list)`?  Note that what you're calling a "word" in your code is actually a full sentence -- you might want to do something like `test_list = test_list[0].split()` to make it a list of multiple strings instead of a list of a single string containing multiple words.

Comment: unfortunately when I test the first answer it only removes the -ed suffix and not the ly or the ing...

Comment: Yes, that's because your original code does `if/elif` so it looked like you only wanted to remove the first one.  Which would make sense if you `split` the phrase into multiple words before removing the suffix from each word.

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this

```
test_list= ['Running the boy gladly jumped']
test_list = list(map(lambda x: x.replace('ing','').replace('ly','').replace('ed',''),test_list))
print(test_list)
```

output

```
['Runn the boy glad jump']
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy to understand solution:

```
test_list = ['Running the boy gladly jumped']

test_words = test_list[0].split()

# removes words that have more than 8 letters
for word in test_words:
    if len(word) >= 8:
        test_words.remove(word)

suffix_list = ['ed', 'ly', 'ing']

final_list = []

for word in test_words:
    if suffix_list[0] == word[-len(suffix_list[0]):]:
        final_list.append(word[0:-len(suffix_list[0])])
        
    elif suffix_list[1] == word[-len(suffix_list[1]):]:
        final_list.append(word[0:-len(suffix_list[1])])
        
    elif suffix_list[2] == word[-len(suffix_list[2]):]:
        final_list.append(word[0:-len(suffix_list[2])])
    
    else:
        final_list.append(word)
        
final_list = [' '.join(final_list)]
            
print (final_list)
```

Output

```
['Runn the boy glad jump']
```

Comment: Thank you! If I wanted to limit the characters in each word to 8, how would I do that? Sorry this was in a technical and I didn't solve it correctly, so i'm eager to learn. I appreciate your explanation!

Comment: After the variable in the second line, test_words, you can add this following line to remove the words that have more than 8 letters.

Comment: ```for word in test_words: ```

Comment: ```if len(word) > 8:```

Comment: ```test_words.remove(word)```

Comment: I've updated that in my answer